# How to diagnose periodic MongoDB slowdown?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Our Mongo database periodically (sometimes once per day) slows down for about 30-40 minutes. The API accessing the database experiences spikes of high latency that occur every 5-10 minutes for this slow period.

Looking at the mongod log file, these 2 lines appear at the start of the slowness, and co-incide with each API latency spike (I've formatted the json for readability):

```
killcursors  keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:91 4157ms
serverStatus was very slow: { 
   after basic: 0, 
   after asserts: 0, 
   after backgroundFlushing: 0, 
   after connections: 0, 
   after cursors: 0, 
   after dur: 0, 
   after extra_info: 0, 
   after globalLock: 0, 
   after indexCounters: 0, 
   after locks: 0, 
   after network: 0, 
   after opcounters: 0, 
   after opcountersRepl: 0, 
   after recordStats: 2359, 
   after repl: 2359, 
   at end: 2359 
}
```

Queries get logged after these because they take several seconds - much much slower than normal.

There doesn't seem to be much/any documentation for `killCursors`, so I don't understand what this log entry means. What is the `r` referring to?

Is the `killCursors` command taking a long time to execute because there is a large number of open cursors to clean up? As far as I know nothing in our application code is explicitly killing cursors, so is this a normal job? It is being logged very often but normally takes 20-120ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***r*** is Intent Shared (IS) lock.
Killcursors is not the issue here. You may need to dig deep to find the actual issue. Check the indexes. Explain all the queries your APIs are using.
You can get an idea from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/qc4AD7kqu4U/7kaI1zwaAwAJ

Answer (score 0):

> By default, the server will automatically close the cursor after 10 minutes of inactivity, or if client has exhausted the cursor.

That said you could have some dropped connections and clean-up was in progress - or other disk/system maintenance job could be in progress in same time window.

To diagnose your performance drop root cause - you could observe [mongo top](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) output, check disk and memory usage and see which particular area there is a spike.

killCursor reference: [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/cursors/#closure-of-inactive-cursors)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Cursors page - I was looking for that this morning and couldn't find it. However this doesn't actually mention `killCursors`. I'll see if I can hop on the box and run `mongotop` and `mongostat` next time this happens...